# Need to correct this form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I've this small form in which the 1st field(title) is required by default. The 2nd and the 3rd are required only in a specific condition.

Case-I: If tool name is filled out, both tool name & tool URL become required.
Case-II: If tool URL is filled out, both tool name & tool URL become required.

I'm not sure it is working as expected. 
Could you please help me correct my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   articleTitle = $('#title').val();
   toolName = $('#toolName').val().trim();
   toolURL = $('#toolURL').val();
   
   
   
   if(((toolName.length>0)&&(toolURL==="")) || ((toolName.length<=0)&&(toolURL!==""))){
   
    $('#toolName').prop('required', true);
    $('#toolURL').prop('required' , true);
    
       
   } else {
    $('#toolName').prop('required', false);
    $('#toolURL').prop('required', false);
  }
   
   
   $("#myForm").submit(function(){
    
    sayHello();
    return false;
   });
   
  });
```

```css
label {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="title">Title:</label> <input type="text" id="title" required> <br /><br />
  <label for="toolName">Tool Name: </label><input type="text" id="toolName"> <br /> <br />
  <label for="toolURL">Tool URL: </label><input type="url" id="toolURL"> <br /> <br />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: The issue is form shouldn't be submitted if only title & toolName are filled out. SImilarly, the form shouldn't be submitted if title & toolURL are filled out. But, currently I'm able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your code quite a bit, please see the comments for a description.

```js
var $toolName = $('#toolName')
var $toolURL = $('#toolURL')
var $toolInputs = $($toolName).add($toolURL)

function sayHelloToMyLittleFriend() {
  alert('sup! form was submitted')
}

$toolInputs.on('change', function(e) {

  var toolName = $toolName.val()
  var toolURL = $toolURL.val()
  
  $toolInputs.prop('required', toolName || toolURL)
})

$('form').submit(function(e) {
  var toolName = $toolName.val()
  var toolURL = $toolURL.val()
  
  var bothFilled = !!toolName && !!toolURL
  var noneFilled = !toolName && !toolURL
  
  if (bothFilled || noneFilled) {
    sayHelloToMyLittleFriend()
    return true
  }
  return false
})
```

```css
label {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
}
/* this will show what element has the required attribute */
[required] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <label for="title">Title:</label> <input type="text" id="title" required> <br /><br />
  <label for="toolName">Tool Name: </label><input type="text" id="toolName"> <br /> <br />
  <label for="toolURL">Tool URL: </label><input type="url" id="toolURL"> <br /> <br />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There is a problem with your code : try to send a first time your form with only title and tool name filled (inputs become required, it's good) then delete the tool name and you cannot send again the form because inputs stay required...

Comment: Still the problem : browser (Chrome in my case) don't call submit function because all required inputs are not filled.

Comment: Yes, that's true! I just realized it now. Also, I'm not able to call my function everytime form submission successfully returns true.

Comment: But how do I call another function on successful form submission? In my code, I'm trying to call another function called sayHello() on successful submission.

Comment: Ah..just added another line of code $('#myForm').on('submit', checkForm, function(){ sayHello() });

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward approach using library-less javascript (rather than jQuery).

*(Albeit, you'll see that it's very similar to the jQuery).*

Whenever data is entered into or removed from the form, the form inputs are checked and, as appropriate, the `required` attributes are added or removed.

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
var toolName = document.getElementById('toolName');
var toolURL = document.getElementById('toolURL');

function checkInputs() {
    if ((toolName.value !== '') || (toolURL.value !== '')) {
        toolName.setAttribute('required','required');
        toolURL.setAttribute('required','required');
    }

        if ((toolName.value === '') && (toolURL.value === '')) {
        toolName.removeAttribute('required');
        toolURL.removeAttribute('required');
    }
}

myForm.addEventListener('keyup', checkInputs, false);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<label for="title">Title:</label> <input type="text" id="title" required> <br /><br />
<label for="toolName">Tool Name: </label><input type="text" id="toolName"> <br /> <br />
<label for="toolURL">Tool URL: </label><input type="url" id="toolURL"> <br /> <br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Great, thanks, could you please help me with using jQuery? I'm new to jQuery and need to implement that in jQuery only.